# What's the best way to implement performant search with potentially 100+ columns in a PostgreSQL DB table?

Tags: database, postgresql, elasticsearch, search

The following picture is something like what I'm trying to accomplish.

1. Several high level entities (tables) e.g: As in image: Companies, People etc.
2. Potentially hundreds of different filtering criteria (each of which is a column in the table)
3. An example query could be: "Give me all **fintech** startups based in **San Fransisco** that **started less than a year ago** and have raised more than **$1 million** funding" (with the bold words being examples of filter values)

Another example query for a different domain could be: "Show me all **vegan** restaurants in **London** where **rating > 4.5** and restaurant age > **5 years** and average monthly customers > **5000**.

[image]

What I need to know is what's the best, most performant way to implement this in order to obtain google-esque type and get instant results experience? I'll have millions of rows in each table, with close to a hundred columns in each table (total several tens of gigabytes of raw data, excluding indexes) which may play the role of being full-text searchable or act as filters/sorting criteria.

I'm using PostgreSQL and have explored postgres full-text search capabilities and I'm also considering ElasticSearch. Is postgres native search + indexed columns the best way to do this? A combination of postgres + elasticsearch? Something else altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres is a Relational database and good for normalizing data and queries involving multiple tables but not very good at searching and filtering the data. **While elasticsearch is very good for searching and filtering**.

Elasticsearch even provides [out of the box filter cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html), which means if you are filtering data based on some columns and again some other users use the same filter criteria, then elastic will not again filter the data and provides the result from its filter cache as explained in the reference link.

I see, both MongoDB and Elastic use case in your application, Elasticsearch is not a database and they are not aiming to replace the relational databases as well and you should always use databases if you can't afford any data loss, please refer [this Elasticsearch discuss link for more info](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-as-a-primary-database/85733/13?u=amitmbm).

**Bottom line is that you should include only the relevant attributes which will be used for search and filtering in your search index in this case, But you should also store your data in Postgres if you are storing transactional data and can't afford the data-loss**

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html is a great read on the resilancy of Elasticsearch and based on your use cases, can you use it as a primary store or not.

Comment: Hey there, I'm not sure how to respond to this as I'm specifically looking for a solution in conjunction with PostgreSQL so I cannot shift to MongoDB

Comment: @AdityaAnand, I've updated my answer based on postgres(rdbms) , please have a look and comment for further questions

Comment: you are extremely pushy mate, I'm not sure whether this is the right answer yet. I will decide on my own time.